# read a text file line by line and check for a substring on 2 of the lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a text file and check for strings

```
with open(my_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'text1' in line:
            f.next()
            if 'text2' in line:
                # do some processing
```

I want to first find the text 'text1' at the beginning of the line then if found I want to check the next line for 'text2' if found then I will do some other processing.  Appears that the f.next() is not moving to the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `line` does not magically get updated when you call `f.next()` (or `next(f)` in Python 3). You would instead have to assign the line returned by `next` to a variable and test against it:

```
with open(my_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'text1' in line:
            try:
                next_line = next(f)
            except StopIteration:
                break # in case we are already at the end of file
            if 'text2' in next_line:
                # do some processing with line and next_line
```

If there can be cases where there are two consecutive lines with `text1` followed by a line of `text2`, however, calling `next(f)` would make it consume the second line of `text1`, making it unable to match `text1` in the next iteration. To remedy that, you can use the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe in the `itertools` documentation to iterate 2 lines at a time over the file instead:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

with open(my_file,'r') as f:
    for line, next_line in pairwise(f):
        if 'text1' in line and 'text2' in next_line:
            # do some processing with line and next_line
```

Comment: I'm getting next_line = f.next()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: `f.next()` is a Python 2 thing. Updated for Python 3 now.

Comment: This doesn't handle 2 text1's followed by a text2.

Comment: @tdelaney Good catch. Updated then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the for loop iteration and use a state variable to decide whether you are in the "test1" case. That way you don't have to juggle a separate `StopIteration` exception.

```
text1_line = ""

with open(my_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if text1_line and 'text2' in line:
            # do some processing
            text1_line = ""
            continue
        text1_line = line if 'text1' in line else ""
```

Comment: This would lose the content of the line containing `text1` for processing.

Comment: @blhsing. You could use the line as the state: set it to None until you find it

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I was waiting for tdelaney to update the answer with that very solution before upvoting. :-)

Comment: Also, if you're going to use a state variable, use `and` instead of nested `if`s

Comment: @blhsing - thanks for catching that, will fix.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - haven't figured out how to use `and` instead.

Comment: Looks good after edit, although I would use `text1_line = 'text1' in line and line` for a cleaner look.

Comment: @tdelaney MadPhysicist means to say that you can write `if text1_line and 'text1' in line` instead of 2 consecutive nested `if`s.

Comment: @blhsing - that's always been my preference but lots of people don't know how python's `and` works and find it confusing. So, I've gone the if/else route instead.

Comment: @blhsing - okay, just wasn't seeing the `and` thing for the nested ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `enumerate` and `readlines`:

```
with open(my_file,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() + ['']
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if 'text1' in line:
            if 'text2' in lines[idx + 1]:
                # do some processing
```

Comment: I'm getting a IndexError: list index out of range on if 'text2' in lines[idx+1]:

Comment: Note that it is generally discouraged to read the entire file into the memory unless you actually need the entire data set in the memory at the same time.

Comment: @magicsword Edited my answer should work now

Comment: This effectively alters the perceived content of the file with an additional blank line, which may have unexpected side effects if there is more processing of the content than what's mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Also, if you're going to read the whole thing in at once, process it outside the with block